# Why does preg_match function validate all fields with a specific field argument?

Tags: php, regex, function

I have a form in which I am using a `preg_match` function to validate fields. I have a generalized function for the matching. The function `validateForm()` is being called earlier on in the script with the appropriate values.

When the function is NOT passed any values, all the fields show the error message despite having correctly matching information. **Generalized function with no arguments:**

```
    function validateForm() {

    if(preg_match()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
} //  end function validateForm
```

When I pass just ONE specific regex/field pair argument, all the fields begin to validate and show the error message when appropriate (so basically the code works as it should despite having a field-specific argument in the function). For example, when I pass this single regex/field argument into `preg_match`, all the fields begin to validate each field correctly, regardless of the fact that I am only checking for the 'City' field in this case. **Example of passing a field-specific argument, in which all the code 'works':**

```
    function validateForm($cityRegex, $city) {

    if(preg_match($cityRegex, $city)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
} //  end function validateForm
```

Can someone explain to me why, when passed a specific argument for a specific field, the function will work for all individual `preg_match` arguments in the code? The script is running as I would want it to, I just do not understand why the specific argument is what makes it validate all fields.

Here is all of the PHP code, if needed:

```
<?php
    $first = '';
    $last = '';
    $phone = '';
    $city = '';
    $state = ''; 
    $error_message = '';

    $firstLastRegex = '/^[a-zA-Z]{2,15}$/';
    $lastRegex = '/^[a-zA-Z]{2,15}$/';
    $phoneRegex = '/^(\(\d{3}\))(\d{3}\-)(\d{4})$/';
    $cityRegex = '/^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}$/';
    $stateRegex = '/^[a-zA-Z]{2}$/';

    $validate_first = '';
    $validate_last = '';
    $validate_phone = '';
    $validate_city = '';
    $validate_state = '';

    $phone_string = '';



    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $first = $_POST['firstName'];
        $last = $_POST['lastName'];
        $phone = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
        $city = $_POST['userCity'];
        $state = $_POST['userState']; 

        $show_form = false;

        $phone_string = str_replace(array('-', '(', ')'), '', $phone);

        $validate_first = validateForm($firstLastRegex, $first);
        $validate_last = validateForm($lastRegex, $last);
        $validate_phone = validateForm($phoneRegex, $phone);
        $validate_city = validateForm($cityRegex, $city);
        $validate_state = validateForm($stateRegex, $state);


        if($validate_first == false) {
                $show_form = true;
                $error_message .= "Please enter your FIRST name between 2 and 15 letters.<br>";
        }

        if($validate_last == false) {
            $show_form = true;
            $error_message .= "Please enter your LAST name between 2 and 15 letters.<br>";
        }

        if($validate_phone == false) {
            $show_form = true;
            $error_message .= "Please enter your phone number in (###)###-### format.<br>";
        }

        if($validate_city == false) {
            $show_form = true;
            $error_message .= "Please enter your city name between 3 and 20 letters.<br>";
        }

        if($validate_state == false) {
            $show_form = true;
            $error_message .= "Please enter your state's abbreviation (Example: CA).<br>";
        }

    } // end if isset();

    else {
        $show_form = true;
        $error_message = "";
    } // end else


    // REGEX FUNCTION

        function validateForm() {

        if(preg_match()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    } //  end function validateForm

?>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question and I read it now multiple times. Are you asking *why* your function works?!

Comment: I was just about to ask the same thing Lol ... The `validateForm` function needs input parameters ... And use them in the `preg_match` function ... So, the function should be `function validateForm($reg,$str) { if(preg_match($reg,$str) )` ... I'm gunna stop there ... Why are you not just using `$validate_first = preg_match($firstLastRegex, $first);` Lol?

Comment: @Rizier123  yes I am asking why it validates all fields when I pass a specific  regex/value argument for only one field.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get it what your question is. (When your question really is, why this code works, it's simply, because you have to specify the regex which is used in preg_match for the filed you want to validate)

Comment: You have to prototype your function, and preg_match() to take arguments.. There is nothing to stop you from inserting code inside the function (but before preg_match) to regurn false when an empty string is passed in.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to have arguments for you function.  The code below will make your validate function work.

```
    function validateForm($regEx, $field) {
    if(preg_match($regEx, $field)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
} //  end function validateForm
```

I also see other potential issues with not checking if post variables are set before using them, and you are setting $show_form = true for all your if/else cases.  I'm sure you can figure everything else out with some debug statements.